# Select Data from XML string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xml

I am trying to select certain values that are posted back to our sql server from an xml into one field as a string..

Example:

```
<?XMLVERSION><result><id>0</id><response>success</response><did>B2A5DY53</did><price>0.00</price></result>
```

How would I select just the value between "price" ' ' "/price"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`ExtractValue()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) function for this:

```
SELECT ExtractValue('<result>
<id>0</id>
<response>success</response>
<did>B2A5DY53</did>
<price>0.00</price>
</result>', '/result/price')
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use the field name like: SELECT ExtractValue(xml_field, '/result/price')?

Comment: Yes, you can use a column name as the first argument of `ExtractValue()`. I only used an XML string since you used one in your example.